# How to open Microsoft Teams meeting in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, microsoft-teams

I am trying to open Microsoft Teams meeting in webview. As I open the meeting url in webview it starts looking for MS Teams app and that is something I don't want, I just want to attend the meeting in my webview.
Please help me to attend MS Teams meeting in webview of my android app

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image: my webview]

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible at this time as the teams we client does not support Android web view.

Answer (score 1):

Using Azure Communication Service you can build your own web client that connects to a teams meeting and can run in a mobile web view,
There are SDKs for most platforms :
https://github.com/Azure/communication#sdks

This is intended to allow you to integrate within your own app.