# How to receive and make MS Teams meeting calls inside my android app

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

I have an app and in which I want to send and receive MS teams meetings calls by using ms-graph-sdk.
I don't want to use any type of webview for this, I want to implement it natively like we have zoom sdk available for android and other platform.
I checked the Call bots sdk of MS [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) and those are not available for Android and I am now confuse like can I send/receive MS Teams calls inside my app or I can't means I need to use official MS Teams Android app to send/receive calls,

I am open to use any SDK like ms-graph sdk or other SDK that MS provide for this functionality.

Please help me to find a proper solution for it.

This question is very much different from [How to open Microsoft Teams meeting in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362264/how-to-open-microsoft-teams-meeting-in-android-webview) so please don't mark this as duplicate.

Comment: [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview), it shows  Android is supported. Here the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/android) to get started with Android and here are some Graph API references [Create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) & [Get Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Hey any updates on this?

Comment: Hi @HunaidHanfee-MSFT, Thanks for your valuable time and input, I checked the links you shared and those are ready to book events in calendar and get and create calls and response is coming in json but I am still not able to receive call as I am not able to find any way to receive call in my app, I am able to get call details but how do I receive call using json response

Comment: Hey, Sorry about Get call API it is to get details of call. Is your issue that you are not able to answer the call(you might be looking for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-answer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? or not even receiving any call on bot?

Comment: Also, this is a good [reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp#readme) its for c# but you can check out the configuration and manifest needs to be done for calling bot.

Comment: HI @HunaidHanfee-MSFT, My question is quite simple, I have an android app and inside that app I want to send and receive calls from MS Teams platform, the reference you shared is to create the extension and that works with MS Teams app and I am not looking any solution like that

Answer (score 0):

[Calling SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/calling-client-samples) to get started with Azure Communication Services for Android.
Here is the document which show how you can [Join your calling app to a Teams meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-teams-interop). It's in public preview and it's not recommended for production workloads.

Thanks